# Why am I getting a NPE after reading a json file into my object?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to read data out of a json file into my family class.
When I try accessing the data I get a NPE

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

    try (Reader reader = new FileReader("family.json")) {

        Family family = gson.fromJson(reader, Family.class);
        System.out.println(family.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Family class

```
public class Family {
List<Person> people;
```

Person class

```
public class Person {
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
```

json file

```
{ "members" : [
{"firstname":"asdf", "lastname":"asdf"}, 
{"firstname":"qwer", "lastname":"qwer"}, 
{"firstname":"fghj", "lastname":"fghj"}
]
```

}

Any help/tips would be appreciated

Comment: How is gson supposed to know that the `members` array in the JSON must populate the `people` list in the Java class? And how are we supposed to know where the NPE comes from if you don't post the relevant code and the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting NPE because, json file is having members list and mapped `Family` class has list of 'people'.

Change people list to members in Family class,

```
List<Person> members;
```

Hope it helps.